# How can I delete macros from word-file when saving with SaveAs2?

Tags: vba, ms-word

So, I have a Word-Template with Macros inside. What do I want to achieve?

When the File is saved I want to save the Word-File as a new docx-File with new name and new destination.

When I click save now the file is already saved correctly with the new name and new destination (also as a *docx file) but the macro is still inside so when I press save now the macro is still executed (this is what I want to remove).

So how can I remove when saving the File all the macros in the new file?

My current code is:

```
Sub FileSave()
'
' saveFile Macro
'
'
    DocDate = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(4, 2)
    GCCName = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(8, 1)
    FileExtension = ".docx"
    matchedStr = GCCName & " - " & DocDate & FileExtension

    matchedStr = Replace(matchedStr, "", "")
    matchedStr = Replace(matchedStr, Chr(13), "")

    ActiveDocument.Save
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "########\"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        matchedStr, FileFormat:= _
        wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a Word template (dotm) you should not open the template to create a document: you should just create a new document right from the start. If the new document is being generated by code then use `Documents.Add` rather than `Documents.New`. The new document will contain *no* macros and can be saved as docx with no problem.

Comment: @max_0512 a docx file - which is the save format your code uses - *cannot* contain macros. It can, however, continue to access any macros in the template it is based on - provided that template is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Word template (dotm) you should not open the template to create a document: you should just create a new document right from the start. If the new document is being generated by code then use `Documents.Add` rather than `Documents.New`. The new document will contain *no* macros and can be saved as docx with no problem.

These days, it is possible to save a template file to a file with the docx extension and to a "document without macros" file format - that will work. (In earlier versions of Word, with the *.dot file format, it did not.)

HOWEVER, the document will still have a *link* to the template and be able to "see" the macros via that link. This may be why you think the macros are being saved in the docx document. If such a file is sent "out of house" (to a location with no way to access the template in the folder where it's stored) then the macros will *not* show up or be available.

If you want to completely dissociate the document from its template, attach it to a different template (usually Normal.dotm because that's available on all Word installations). Example based on the code in the question:

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = NormalTemplate
```

This needs to be at the end of the code since it will dissociate it from the code that's performing the action.

A tip for the code in the question: working with `ActiveDocument` can be unreliable - it's not certain that it will always be the document intended (the user could activate a different one, for example). A more reliable approach is to work with a `Document` object. The same applies to other things, such as tables. For example:

```
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim tbl as Word.Table
Set doc = ActiveDocument
' do things with the document...
Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
' do things with the table
DocDate = tbl.Cells(4,2).Range.Text
GCCName = tbl.Cell(8, 1).Range.Text
doc.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative for docm files, taken from my project**

NameNoExtension is the name of the new file. Put your path where SelectSaveDir() is in my code. The code opens a copy of the file where the the code is, deletes all the vba Modules and saves the copied file as docx.

```vb
Sub SaveCopyAsDocx(ByVal NameNoExtension As String)
    Dim NewDocument As Object
    Set NewDocument = Documents.Add(ThisDocument.FullName)

    Dim Modul As Object

    For Each Modul In NewDocument.VBProject.VBComponents
        If Modul.Name <> "ThisDocument" Then
            NewDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Modul
        End If
    Next

    NewDocument.SaveAs SelectSaveDir() & "\" & NameNoExtension & ".docx"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is quite unnecessary. As per my comment addressed to the OP yesterday, simply saving in the docx format is sufficient to remove all macros.

Comment: @macropod This is simply not true. If the main document is docm file (normal file with macros) and you try to save it as docx, Word 2016 will refuse to save it as docx file, you have to remove the macros before.

Comment: You really do need to learn how Word works - your claim is entirely false. @majka Word 2016, like all other Word versions from 2007 on, will simply warn you if you do it through the GUI; no such warning is given - and no supposed limitation exists - when saving in VBA via SaveAs or SaveAs2 with FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument (which the OP uses) specified.